# google drive download document using javascript :can't download files

Tags: javascript, download, google-drive-api, documents

I have download documents from google drive by using Google drive API with java. But i want to use javascript instead of java. So i am using  Drive API client libraries java script code.
i am using the below code for achieving this

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
}
```

My problem is i can able to display all file names and contents. but i can't download the files. Do i need to do any extra code? How can i save the files in my local system. any suggestions ?
Note: i can get value in `file.downloadUrl` if i paste the downloadUrl in the browser it won't give any result ,just show a blank page.

Comment: This is all you need to download a file, is it possible to share some error output and etc?

Answer (score 0):

"if i paste the downloadUrl in the browser it won't give any result" is correct because when you GET using a browser there is no authentication header. If you check the status you will see a 401 error.

I use "Authorization: '**OAuth** ' + gapi.auth.getToken()['access_token']" rather than '**Bearer**'. I'm not sure if that is significant.

Are you sure the downloadUrl is current? This is a short-lived attribute, so it's possible the link has expired.

It's also possible the access token is invalid. As Burcu said, your answer is probably within the response and status to your xhr get.